# Is an object in first level cache

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, caching

How can I find out if a certain `HibernateProxy` is in the first level cache?

The code is roughly

```
for (HibernateObject obj : objects) {
    if (HibernateUtils.isHibernateProxyInCache(
        obj.getExpensiveLazyObject())
    ) {
        display(obj.getExpensiveLazyObject());
    } else {
        display("click here to see expensive lazy object");
    }
}
```

the code I need is `HibernateUtils.isHibernateProxyInCache`, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isPropertyInitialized%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

Calling `HibernateUtils.isHibernateProxyInCache(obj.getExpensiveLazyObject())` would initialize the proxy to the expensive lazy object, so your method would always return true.

Comment: are you saying that simply calling `getX` would initialize the proxy? Can you please give me a link to the piece of documentation stating that? So if I understand you correctly, I need to do `Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized(obj,"expensiveLazyObject")`, right?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You probably just need Hibernate.isInitialized(obj.getExpensiveLazyObject()).

Comment: thanks. But I'm not sure I understand what "initialized" mean. Can you refer me to the docs? I'm not sure that "initialized" means "in first level cache".

Comment: initialized means : "the proxy has been initialized". Initially, a proxy to an entity only holds the entity's ID. Once you call any method on the proxy object, it first loads the actual entity instance, with all its fields, from the database, and then delegates to this entity instance to execute the method. Initialized means "the entity state has been loaded from the database". If the proxy is still attached to its Hibernate session, then an initialized proxy should be in the cache. If it's not what you need, then please elaborate, and look at the method *contains* in Session.